# React UseContext on Page Refresh Loses Data

Tags: reactjs, react-context

UserContextLib.js

```
    createContext, useState, useEffect,
} from 'react';
import { API } from 'aws-amplify';

const UserContext = createContext(null);

const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    async function LoadUser() {
        console.log('loading user');
        return API.get('users', '/user');
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        async function onLoad() {
            try {
                setIsLoaded(true);
                const userInformation = await LoadUser();
                setUser(userInformation);
                setIsLoaded(false);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
                setIsLoaded(false);
            }
        }
        onLoad();
    }, []);

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{
            user,
            setUser,
            setIsLoaded,
            isLoading,
        }}
        >
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};

export { UserProvider, UserContext };
```

Component.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { UserContext } from '../../libs/UserContextLib';
import { AppContext } from '../../libs/ContextLib';
// import { onError } from '../../libs/ErrorLib';
import FormDialogue from '../formDialogue/FormDialogue';
import Loader from '../loader/Loader';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: '1rem',
    },
    cardWrapper: {
        width: 'calc(100% - 14em)',
        minHeight: 80,
        display: 'flex',
        background: '#F7F9FA',
        margin: '1rem 0rem',
        border: 'none',
        borderRadius: '0px',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        boxShadow: 'none',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: '0rem 1rem',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
            width: 'calc(100% - 4em)',
        },
    },
    cardContent: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 16,
        margin: '0rem 1rem',
        alignItems: 'center',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
            margin: '0rem',
            fontSize: 13,
        },
    },
    pos: {
        marginBottom: 12,
    },
}));

export default function ProcessorSettings() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const { user, isLoading, setIsLoaded } = useContext(UserContext);
    const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AppContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function onLoad() {
            if (!isAuthenticated) {
                return;
            }

            if (user === null) {
                setIsLoaded(true);
            }

            console.log('loading processor settings');
        }

        onLoad();
    }, [isAuthenticated]);

    function renderIntegrations(data) {
        console.log(isAuthenticated);
        console.log(user);

        return (

            <div className={classes.root}>
                {data.Item.integrations.map((item) => (
                    <Card className={classes.cardWrapper}>
                        <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                            <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                                <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                                    Logo
                                </Typography>
                            </CardContent>
                            <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                                <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                                    {item.name}
                                </Typography>
                            </CardContent>
                        </CardContent>
                        <FormDialogue status={item.connected} />
                    </Card>
                ))}
            </div>

        );
    }

    return (

        isLoading ? (
            <Loader />
        ) : (
            renderIntegrations(user)
        )

    );
}
```

App.Js

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from './libs/PrivateRoute';
import PublicRoute from './libs/PublicRoute';
import { AppContext } from './libs/ContextLib';
import { UserProvider } from './libs/UserContextLib';
import LoginPage from './screens/LoginPage';
import SignUpPage from './screens/SignupPage';
import NotFoundPage from './screens/NotFound';
import Processor from './components/processor/ProcessorSettings';
import SettingsPanel from './components/settings/settingsPanel';
import AppLayout from './screens/layouts/appLayout/AppLayout';

function App() {
    const [isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    const [isAuthenticating, setIsAuthenticating] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
        onLoad();
    }, []);

    async function onLoad() {
        try {
            await Auth.currentSession();
            userHasAuthenticated(true);
        } catch (e) {
            if (e !== 'No current user') {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

        setIsAuthenticating(false);
    }

    return (
        !isAuthenticating && (
            <AppContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated }}>
                <UserProvider>
                    <Router>
                        <Switch>
                            <PublicRoute exact path="/login">
                                <LoginPage />
                            </PublicRoute>
                            <PublicRoute exact path="/signup">
                                <SignUpPage />
                            </PublicRoute>
                            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Processor} layout={AppLayout} />
                            <PrivateRoute exact path="/processor" component={Processor} layout={AppLayout} />
                            <PrivateRoute exact path="/settings" component={SettingsPanel} layout={AppLayout} />
                            <NotFoundPage />
                        </Switch>
                    </Router>
                </UserProvider>
            </AppContext.Provider>
        )
    );
}

export default App;
```

Above is my simple setup using React Hooks & Context API to manage user state. The above works fine when I login into the app for first time. The data is mapped and passed from UserContext as expected to the component. The UserContext hook fetches the persisted data from the server via AWS Amplify API Gateway Config.

**THE PROBLEM**

When I refresh the browser I get the error

> Cannot read property 'Item' of null

The data from UserContext is not fetched in the UseEffect lifecycle method in UserContextLib from the server and my app crashes due user object being null. I suspect it is something to do with my misunderstanding of React Lifecycle and me being a beginner with the framework and Context API.

If anyone could provide some clues I'd be very thankful.

Comment: When you refresh the page the Context is cleaned. Thus now it doesn't know whether user has logged in or not.

Comment: Thanks @kunquan apologies if I'm stating the obvious... so if I'm correct I'll need to add isAuthenticated context within UserContext so the UserContext knows whether the user is Logged in?

Answer (score 2):

Managed to resolve issue I was missing a conditional before trying to render data.

```
                    {data && data.Item.integrations.map((item) => (
                    <Card className={classes.cardWrapper}>
                        <Grid direction="row" container alignContent="space-between" justifyContent="center">
                            <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                                <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                                    <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                                        <div>
                                            {images.filter((image) => item.name === image.name).map((filteredImage) => (
                                                <Typography>{filteredImage.svg}</Typography>
                                            ))}
                                        </div>
                                    </Typography>
                                </CardContent>
                                <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                                    <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                                        {item.name}
                                    </Typography>
                                </CardContent>

                            </CardContent>
                        </Grid>

                        <FormDialogue status={item.connected} name={item.integrationName} />
                    </Card>
                ))}
            </div>
```